# Mongodb not asking for password when executing query from js file

Tags: mongodb, authentication

I have below query.js file which I want to execute with mongo shell:

```
use jonty
db.passprt.find({})
```

It should give the desired result by executing the command `mongo < query.js -u "root" -p --authenticationDatabase "admin"` .

But the mongo shell doesn't asks for password and shows login failed. What can I do so that it asks me for for password before I execute queries from a file. It is to be noted that simple login is working fine.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: remove `-p` from the string. I believe you can add encryption too, just adding --tls but this you should check in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [mongo Core Options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption-mongo-password):

> To force mongo to prompt for a password, enter the `--password` option as the last option and leave out the argument.

So

```
mongo query.js -u "root" --authenticationDatabase "admin" --password
```

should do the trick

Comment: now it is asking for password but it is giving error in file query.js, although there looks to be no error in the file when we see it. It gives missing semicolon in first line. But even after putting semicolon, it gives the same error.

Comment: Maybe try `mongo -u "root" --authenticationDatabase "admin" jonty --password <<< "db.passprt.find({})"`